# Unity CS1503 "Cannot convert..." at Instancing Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to "spawn" a GameObject prefab using `Instantiate`.
My code for instantiating is:

```cs
ObjInstance = Instantiate(original, original.transform.position, 0) as Rigidbody2D;
```

It throws error `CS 1503: Argument3: Cannot convert from "int" to "UnityEngine.Quaternion"`

I tried to put those coordinates in a `Vector3()` and it gives the same error. I followed some tutorials but that line throws me the same error.

I don't have any idea of what to try now.

Comment: Use Quaternion.Identity as third parameter to instantiate your object without a specific rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to instantiate gameobject like this you have to define Quaternion parameter.

Please read carefully this console error.

> Blockquote Argument3: Cannot convert from "int" to "UnityEngine.Quaternion

Simply says do not able to use integer value in instantiate method at third argument which needs Quaternion vector.

Please change your 3rd value in your Instantiate method and use Quaternion variable...

Comment: Whats a Quaternion vector? More or less, how it would be?

Comment: Quaternion vectors are defines your object rotation and orientations in 3d space. If you develop your project at 2d just ignore it and use new Quaternion(0,0,0,0) and pass this error..

Addition: If  want to instantiate at transform position like this you have not to use quaternion vector(third value). Please look instantiate method variaties more careful...